# jQuery hide elements depending on the dropdown selection option?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide a number of elements depending on the dropdown selection option number...Please have a look:

HTML:

```
<div class="box_1">some content</div>
<div class="box_2">some content</div>
<div class="box_3">some content</div>
<div class="box_4">some content</div>
<div class="box_5">some content</div>

<select id="select">
<option value="1">Show 1 boxes</option>
<option value="2">Show 2 boxes</option>
<option value="3">Show 3 boxes</option>
<option value="4">Show 4 boxes</option>
<option value="5">Show 5 boxes</option>
</select>
```

So far my JS looks like this:

```
jQuery("#select").change(function() {
     var currSelection = jQuery("option:selected",this).val();

});
```

And I am not sure how to proceed from here...

So if 4 is selected for example, I want to hide the fifth box element and if 3 is selected, I want to hide the 4th and 5th box element...etc..
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery("#select").change(function() {
    $("div[class^='box_']").show().filter(":gt("+(parseInt($(this).val()) -1 )+")").hide();
}).change();
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q8wvz/1/)**

Comment: Thanks-on my side it threw an error..."uncaught exception class^=.."

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very concisely using [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice) (which works since jQuery objects are array-ish):

```
jQuery("#select").change(function() {
   $("div[class^='box']").hide().slice(0, $(this).val()).show();
}).change();
```

[**Try it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/XEcsm/)